# Using jQuery on to bind plugin functionality with AJAX rendered HTML

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

**Problem/misunderstanding)** : How to bind jQuery plugin functionality such as [xEditable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) or [Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) to dynamic HTML fragments that are appended to a page

**Example of simple dynamic event based scenario**  I have appended data to a page, but needed to dynamically attach a click event, this seems simple as I have an event to bind.

```
$(document).on('click','.noteDelete',function (e) {
    var agreed = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete?");
    if (agreed == true) {
        var elememt = $(this);
        var note    = elememt.data('note');
        deleteNote(elememt,note);
    }

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

The jQuery on : `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

**Example of how you would bind plugins** Typically you would bind like so:

```
$(".select2Search").select2({
            placeholder: "Search..",
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: { 
              url: "<g:createLink controller='example' action='search'/>",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    format:'json',
                    q: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
              return {results: data.values};
            }
          }
        });
```

**Question** So... as I'm not binding an event, what is the appropriate approach for dynamically binding the plugin functionality to the AJAX rendered HTML fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Most plugins do not work on dynamic content. That would require all their actions to be connected to the DOM via delegated events. Any plugins that change the DOM, like `Select2` does, would not know *when* the new content was added.

The simplest solution is to apply plugins, e.g. based on a class, to only the loaded content, just after the content is loaded. That usually means adding a function call in the `success` of the Ajax call, or at least broadcasting a custom event (e.g. via `trigger()`) that can be caught at the document level.

*If you can show your loading code, I may be able to suggest which option is best suited to you.*